# dplyr mutate with str_locate_all

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I would like to add the Start and End positions of Strings into a df. I know how to do it with str_locate but how do I bind all expected hits using str_locate_all?

Example for str_locate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

pattern <- "HelloHiHelloHi"

df <- data.frame(
  Text = c("Hello", "HelloHi", "Hi")
)

df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Start = str_locate(pattern, Text)[[1]],
                    End = str_locate(pattern, Text)[[2]]) 

#result

  Text    Start   End
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 Hello       1     5
2 HelloHi     1     7
3 Hi          6     7
```

I am looking to get the following result:

```
  Text        Start     End              
  <chr>       <int> <int>           
1 Hello           1     5 
2 Hello           8    12 
3 HelloHi         1     7 
4 HelloHi         8    14 
5 Hi              6     7 
6 Hi             13    14
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you do `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Start = str_locate_all(pattern, Text),
                    End = str_locate_all(pattern, Text))` it will add all points as nested lists

Comment: How do you unnest those lists such that you get a row for each location?

Comment: Well, there is `unnest()` but are you sure that they will always be the same size?

Comment: Yes I am sure they are always the same size. I tried: df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Start = str_locate_all(pattern, Text),
                    End = str_locate_all(pattern, Text)) %>% unnest(Start) 
but this doesn't result in a format as shown above.

Comment: It shouldn't since you have more elements here. Maybe I am not understanding it well.

Comment: I added the desired result above.

Comment: Well, it's almost there. You can play with indexing the `str_locate_all()` and you ll get it. I dont have more time, sorry. :)

Comment: Could solve it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(pos = list(
  data.frame(
   str_locate_all(pattern, Text)))) %>% unnest(pos) 

#result
  Text    start   end
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 Hello       1     5
2 Hello       8    12
3 HelloHi     1     7
4 HelloHi     8    14
5 Hi          6     7
6 Hi         13    14
```

The above no longer works with the new version of dplyr. I now use:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(
      start = str_locate_all(pattern, text) %>%
          map(~ .x[,1]),
      end = str_locate_all(pattern, text) %>%
          map(~ .x[,2])) %>%
      unnest(cols=c(start, end))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or an option with `base R` (other than the `stringr` already used)

```
out <-  do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, Text = df$Text, 
           str_locate_all(pattern, df$Text)))
row.names(out) <- NULL
```